# Parsing large number of files in parallel and summarizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a tool that generates a large number of files (ranging from hundreds of thousands to few millions) whenever it runs. All these files can be read independently of each other. I need to parse them and summarize the information.

Dummy example of generated files:

```
File1:
NAME=John AGE=25 ADDRESS=123 Fake St
NAME=Jane AGE=25 ADDRESS=234 Fake St

File2:
NAME=Dan AGE=30 ADDRESS=123 Fake St
NAME=Lisa AGE=30 ADDRESS=234 Fake St
```

Summary - counts how many times an address appeared across all files:

```
123 Fake St - 2
234 Fake St - 2
```

I want to use parallelization to read them, so `multiprocessing` or `asyncio` come to mind (I/O intensive operations). I plan to do the following operations in a single unit/function that will be called in parallel for each file:

1. Open the file, go line by line
2. Populate a unique dict containing the information provided by this file specifically
3. Close the file

Once I am done reading all the files in parallel, and have one dict per file, I can now loop over each dict and summarize as needed.

The reason I think I need this two step process, is I can't have multiple parallel calls to that function directly summarize and write to a common summary dict. That will mess things up.

But that means I will consume a large amount of memory (due to holding those many hundreds of thousands to millions of dicts in memory).

What would be a good way to get the best of both worlds - runtime and memory consumption - to meet this objective?

Comment: How big are those files? Can be the summarization computed *"on-fly"*?

Comment: They are "log-like" in nature. Each line having bunch of key=value pairs. They can range from very small (few lines) to very large (hundreds of MBs sized text file). The act of summarization is to correlate the key=value pairs across all files, maybe something like count how many times a key=value pair shows up or something like that.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there 2 sample (small) files and expected output? Maybe I can come up with solution.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Added an example

Comment: Have you considered using a simple database, so you can just update counts in the database every time you finish processing a file, before you start the next?

Comment: How many address entries are there overall, and how many *different* addresses are there overall?

Comment: And same per file, i.e., how many address entries are there per file (on average) and how many *different* addresses are there per file (on a Etage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments here's example using [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

Each process reads one file line by line and sends the result back to main process to collect.

```py
import re
import multiprocessing
from collections import Counter

pat = re.compile(r"([A-Z]{2,})=(.+?)(?=[A-Z]{2,}=|$)")


def process_file(filename):
    c = Counter()
    with open(filename, "r") as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            d = dict(pat.findall(line))
            if "ADDRESS" in d:
                c[d["ADDRESS"]] += 1

    # send partial result back to main process:
    return c


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # you can get filelist for example from `glob` module:
    files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]

    final_counter = Counter()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        # iterate over files and update the final Counter:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_file, files):
            final_counter.update(result)

    # print final Counter:
    for k, v in final_counter.items():
        print("{:<20} {}".format(k, v))
```

Prints:

```
123 Fake St          2
234 Fake St          2
```

---

Note: You can use [`tqdm`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) module to get nice progress bar, for example:

```py
...
from tqdm import tqdm
...

for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_file, tqdm(files)):

...
```

Comment: This works fabulously!! And I have never used `tqdm` before and seeing that progress bar go double the speed of sequential logic is so satisfying!!!!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Redis Queue [RQ](https://python-rq.org) is likely the most appropriate datastore for this use-case. This will allow you to process the files in parallel while managing resources without needing to use multiprocessing—while you still could if you really needed to.

The benefit with this approach, in contrast with solely using `multiprocessing` or `async` is that it scales horizontally when used in conjunction with Redis Cluster.

### Pseudocode

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue, Retry

def do_work(f):
    if maximum_filesize_in_queue_exceeds_resources():
      raise ResourcesUnavailableError
    else:
        f.read()
        ...

def run(files_to_process):
    q = Queue()

    for f in files_to_process:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            q.enqueue(do_work, f, retry=Retry(max=3, interval=[10, 30, 60]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files_to_process = ("foo", "bar", "baz")

    run(files_to_process)
    ...
```

### Results

You could use Redis to also store the results from each worker, and use rq's success hook to update the summary, which would also be stored in Redis. Once all queues have completed—you could then print a report with result and summary information stored in Redis.

## References

1. https://redis.com
2. https://python-rq.org
3. https://redis.io/docs/manual/scaling/

Comment: I am going to try this out (I have not used Redis before and have no idea what it works) and read up on it. I don't know what a Redis cluster is - but without it - are the redis process workers utilizing multiple threads/cores/processes? How do they run in parallel? Redis makes use of multiprocessing/async under the hood?

Comment: @shikhanshu Redis is a highly performant key value store. Redis Queue implements a queueing system on top of Redis. See distributed programming, specifically the parallel job queue pattern.